# when I try to connect to mongodb I got these error

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

(node:9804) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Connection errorMongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]

Comment: Please add some code, how are you connecting to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

keep your mongodb compass open then try running the code from your IDE.